# Create more items in Workflow

Tags: designer-workflow

I have workflow created in sharepoint designer associated with the list. When the workflow runs we need to create 10 items in another list. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

try to use `SPWorkflowEventReceiver`

Comment: A nice guide for that is found here: http://netsourcecode.blogspot.se/2011/09/spworkfloweventreceiver-class-and.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the Create List Item action to create the desired items.